# python 3 variable used in another variable's name?

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.x, var

in python 3 (with tkinter) i have the following images:

```
SqImg1 = PhotoImage(file='SqImg1.gif')
SqImg2 = PhotoImage(file='SqImg2.gif')
SqImg3 = PhotoImage(file='SqImg3.gif')
SqImg4 = PhotoImage(file='SqImg4.gif')
...
```

i also have a function that needs to return one of those images based on a variable.  so if the function determines var to be 1, it needs to return SqImg1...

```
def returnImage():
    list = ['ale', 'boo', 'boo', 'cat', 'doe', 'boo', 'eel']
    var = 0
    for item in list:
        if item == 'boo':
            var += 1
    return SqImg[var]
```

i would want the above to return SqImg3

this is probably simple, but i can't seem to find what im looking for with google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options

- Create a dictionary and map the strings to the actual variables. E.g., 
  `d = {};    d["boo"] = img3`
- Call eval() if your images are numbered correctly.. e.g., `return eval("sqlimg%d" % var)`

The first option is probably what you're looking for unless you have special circumstances

Comment: dictionary!  should have known that.  works great, just construct a string and look it up.  'SqImg3':SqImg3

Answer (score 2):

There's your mistake straight away:

```
SqImg1 = PhotoImage(file='SqImg1.gif')
SqImg2 = PhotoImage(file='SqImg2.gif')
SqImg3 = PhotoImage(file='SqImg3.gif')
SqImg4 = PhotoImage(file='SqImg4.gif')
...
```

should be:

```
SqImg = [
PhotoImage(file='SqImg1.gif'),
PhotoImage(file='SqImg2.gif'),
PhotoImage(file='SqImg3.gif'),
PhotoImage(file='SqImg4.gif'),
...
]
```

or even:

```
SqImg = [ PhotoImage(file='SqImg{}.gif'.format(i) for i in range(1, n) ]
```

Comment: to save space?  memory?  whats the advantage (other than it looks much better)?

Comment: @Thomas Kirkpatrick: to avoid repetition. Repeating yourself in code is often a sign that things could be done better.

Comment: @Thomas: Looking better is also a benefit. In this case though it's going to give you cleaner code.